# How to snif communication traffic between Instant Messenger on two android device

Tags: android, wireshark, traffic, instant-messaging, network-traffic

I want to sniff the traffic between wechat app installed on two android devices. I have wireshark installed on my laptop and im using my home wifi. they are all connected to my wifi and their IP addresses shows they are on the same network, 192.168.0.2(phone), 192.168.0.14 (laptop), 192.168.0.15(tablet). I started sending messages to and from the two android devices, however, I hardly see any traffic captured from either device on the wireshark. Aside from the laptop's ip addresses, other Ip addresses captured are public addresses I could ping the devices from any of the device. Does it mean the devices are communicating via public address? Using the arp -a command gave the following command

```
C:\Users\laptop>arp -a
```

I got the following results

> Interface: 192.168.0.14 --- 0xf

Internet Address        Physical Address        Type

192.168.0.1             7c-03-4c-99-fd-c1       dynamic

192.168.0.2           84-51-81-b5-93-96     dynamic

192.168.0.5           0c-84-dc-78-d2-5b     dynamic

192.168.0.8           a4-17-31-f6-cb-29     dynamic

192.168.0.15          ac-22-0b-a2-d1-20     dynamic

192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static

224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static

224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static

239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

How do I properly sniff the communication traffic between this two android devices?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I properly sniff the communication traffic between this two android devices?

It looks as if you're running Windows on the machine on which you want to sniff the communication, so your options are:

1. get [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) and capture in monitor mode - I'm not sure whether it can decrypt WEP or WPA/WPA2-protected traffic, though, so if your network is using WEP or WPA/WPA2 (which it should be), you may have to capture the traffic, save it to a file, and load it into Wireshark to decrypt it.
2. get another sniffer that can capture in monitor mode and either decrypt it or write it out in a format Wireshark can read, if your network is using WEP or WPA/WPA2; those cost money, however.
3. get [an AirPcap adapter](http://www.riverbed.com/products/steelcentral/steelcentral-riverbed-airpcap.html); Wireshark doesn't cost money, but the AirPcap adapter does.
4. use [Npcap](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) and, if your adapter supports monitor mode with the vendor driver (which is also necessary if you're using Network Monitor), capture in monitor mode.

See [the Wireshark Wiki "how to decrypt 802.11" page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) for information on what you need to do if you want to be able to decrypt WEP or WPA/WPA2 traffic.

Comment: Good answer by @GuyHarris. To add to this, to sniff correctly you will also have to find out which WiFi channel the Android devices are connected to and start the capture on that channel.

Comment: I installed Microsoft Network Monitor and tried capturing the traffic while I was sending messages between the android devices. I tried capturing from the channel the devices are using (channel 6). also I tried capturing from all channels. However, the captured file doesn't seem to capture any traffic from the android device. I can see every other traffic. Im wondering what could be wrong?